# Facebook Share Dialog/Feed Dialog on iOS - how to know if share button or cancel button is tapped

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, share

I was trying to implement a Facebook share dialog in my iOS app. I tried both the Share Dialog

```
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/
```

and Feed dialog

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/
```

In both the cases I was able to actually share my content, but my problem is I cannot track whether the user actually "Shared" or "Cancel"ed out.

The links above show handlers (even comments are there) which gets fired if the user actually shares the content. But when the code is actually run, it always returns positive or in other words I'm not being able to distinguish if the cancel button was hit or the share button.

Please point me out if I'm missing out anything, or if anyone else has faced the same issue.

Thanks,

Comment: In your second link there is an example of how to know if user canceled the sharing.

Comment: @giorashc yes, but when that code snippet is run on a device the flow never reaches the success block even if the user actually shared the content and that's the big mystery. It always enters the 'user cancelled' block. Even the example codebase provided in the git repo in that link behaves exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating just in case this helps anyone, the following link finally worked for me:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/#nativepostcontroller
```

Though it had it's limitations (doesn't run on iOS < 6), but it successfully returns me when the user cancels out the dialog. Here's the code I used:

```
BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                  initialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url]
                  image:nil
                  url:url
                  handler:^(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogResult result, NSError *error) {                                                  
                  if(result == 0)
                  {
                       //Fire our callback

                  }
                  else{
                        NSLog(@"USER CANCELLED");
                  }
          }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the explicit result on your console.

```
FBDialogs.PresentShareDialog(myAction,"altimeterthree:share","flight",(call, results, error) => {
    if(call != null)show("Call = " + call.ToString());
    if(results != null)Console.WriteLine("Results = "+results.ToString());
    if(error != null)Console.WriteLine("Error = "+FBErrorUtility.UserMessage(error));
});
```

Here's what the console output looks like. Notice that the result is also in the call info.

```
2014-05-11 10:09:26.067 AltimeterThree[18988:60b] Call = <FBAppCall: 0x19e02350, ID: 4589F102-3D11-40D5-BC95-1A1852B341AC
 dialogData: <FBDialogsData: 0x19e04e20, method: ogshare
 arguments: {
    action =     {
        flight =         {
            data =             {
            };
            description = "my description";
            "fbsdk:create_object" = 1;
            id = 1413672752238899;
            image =             (
                                {
                    url = "<UIImage: 0x147f9180>";
                    "user_generated" = true;
                }
            );
            title = "Flight 23";
            type = "altimeterthree:flight";
            url = "http://http://samples.ogp.me/1413756595563848";
        };
    };
    actionType = "altimeterthree:share";
    previewPropertyName = flight;
}
 results: {
    completionGesture = cancel;
    didComplete = 1;
}>
>
2014-05-11 10:09:26.070 AltimeterThree[18988:60b] Results = {
    completionGesture = cancel;
    didComplete = 1;
}
```